# Asymptotic time complexity O(sqrt(n)log(n)n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

```
for(int i=1; i*i <= n; i = i+1) {
   for(int j = n; j >= 1; j/4)   {
      for(int k = 1; k <= j; k=k+1) {
         f();
      }
   }
}
```

Why is the asymptotic complexity of this function `O(n^{3/2})`? I think, it should be `O(sqrt(n)log(n)n)`. Is this the same to `O(sqrt(n)n)`? Then, it would be `O(n^{3/2})`..

- Outer loop is `O(sqrt(n))`.
- first inner loop is `O(log(n))`.
- second inner loop is `O(n)`.

Comment: Fix those typos, and try to justify why you think it would be `O(sqrt(n) n log n)`.

Comment: You can't just multiply the running times for dependent loops (the inner-most one isn't `O(n)` for each `j`). You'll need to count the actual number of times the inner-most loop runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer two loops (over `i` and `j`) have bounds that depend on `n`, but the inner loop (over `k`) is bounded by `j`, not `n`.

Note that the inner loop iterates `j` times; assuming `f()` is `O(1)`, the cost of the inner loop is `O(j)`.

Although the middle loop (over `j`) iterates `O(log n)` times, the actual value of `j` is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) starting with `n`.  Because this geometric series (`n + n/4 + n/16 + ...`) sums to `4/3*n`, the cost of the middle loop is `O(n)`.

Since the outer loop iterates `sqrt(n)` times, this makes the total cost `O(n^(3/2))`

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!